# How to make the 'Module Updates' report available again?

Tags: 7, updating, log-messages

I have a 7.18 Drupal site running since a long time without updates. The update manager was deactivated since then as well.

Now I had to move the site to another server and after reactivating the update manager, it does not work properly. I have the status message that there are updates available, but the paths `admin/reports/updates` or `admin/reports/updates/update` only lead to the reports overview page.

Does anyone have a hint about how to fix this?

Comment: Make sure you've re-enabled the Update Manager module, and then clear the cache. You should be good to go.

Comment: @Clive I was about to write this as an answer. Any reason you left it as a comment? Certainly looks like an answer to me.

Comment: @Mołot Because if it's fixed by enabling the update manager, we have a dupe for that...and if it was fixed by a cache-clear it comes under the "was solved by a cache-clear/simple typographic error" bracket. And if neither, then there'll be a different answer altogether :)

Comment: Oh, i think i have a memory issue here. Clearing the cache led to a white screen and running the update.php script shows a Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted... I'll have to talk to my hoster first. Thanks anyway Clive, and when this one's a dupe, i guess i should delete my question then?

Comment: @Volker if it is a duplicate, it should be closed as duplicate. But I wasn't able to find any "original" for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a list of items to check:

- Make sure core module `update` (= Update Manager) is enabled.
- Clear all caches: if you get a WSOD while doing so, it indicates memory shortage.
- Try running `update.php`: if you get a Fatal error like "Allow memory size of ... bytes exhausted", it indicates memory shortage.
- Verify if it is a memory shortage issue: try increasing the memory a bit to check if there is any difference.